# Regex match double curly braces nested

Tags: php, regex, double-brace-initialize

would regex matches while/loop double curly braces contains double curly braces?

```
<?php
$str = '<html lang="{{var doc-lang}}">
<head>
<title>{{var doc-title}}</div>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" {{while products}}>
        {{var name}}
        {{var sku}}
        {{var barcode}}
    </div {{while end}}>
</div>
</body>
</html>';
```

Can we get

```
<div class class="row"', [products], {{var name}}, {{ var sku}} and {{var barcode}}
```

from `$str`?

I only can think of this Reg

```
\<((.*)\{\{while\s+(.*)\}\}(.*)\{\{while\s+end\}\})\>
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iG1lJ5/1)

Comment: Sorry, {{var=doc-lang}}, {{var=doc-title}} does not have '=' sign, replace with empty space.

Comment: Obviously you are trying to come up with your own templating system. There are plenty of flexible systems out there already available, Twig is exceptional  http://twig.sensiolabs.org

Comment: @Zanderwar, that's correct, but we are doing single-file applications, we can not afford an add-on classes.

Comment: Fair enough :) Best of luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\s*(.*\{\{while\s+.*(?:\r?\n.*)+\{\{while\s+end.*)/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE6jQ1/1)

---

Also to get them separately *(as you mentioned in the question and comment)*, Try this:

```
/\s*(?:(.*)\s+\{\{while\s+(.*)\}\}.*\r?\n\s*(.*)\r?\n\s*(.*)\r?\n\s*(.*)\r?\n.*)/
```

And you can get what you need like this:

```
'$1', [$2], $3, $4 and $5
```

**Output:**

```
'<div class class="row"', [products], {{var name}}, {{ var sku}} and {{var barcode}}
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE6jQ1/2)

Comment: Thanks @Shafizadeh that is almost right, but can I get them separated not in one block?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves the issue I am raising, but on the other hand my {{if var sku > 0 }} {{var sku}} {{end if}} regex is not functioning no more with this solution, kindly help get the IF block.